# Windows Phone 7: Grab current url and use to Reload my browserpage

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser, webbrowser-control, refresh, reload

how can i refresh/reload my browserpage in my app?
i have a webbrowser created to dinamically retrieve a random page from my site, now i want to capture the actual url and use it for the refresh button and for the "open in browser button".

Basically i need to retrieve the current url and use it to refresh it: this is my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the webBrowser control is caleld `EmbeddedBrowser`.

Refresh:

```
EmbeddedBrowser.Navigate(EmbeddedBrowser.Source.AbsoluteUri);
```

Launch in IE:

```
var wbt = new WebBrowserTask
{
    URL = EmbeddedBrowser.Source.AbsoluteUri
};

wbt.Show();
```